# IE7 - display:inline submit button does not change position when select input expands

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, position

I have a select box that expands depending on its content (dynamic content with PHP). The submit buttons position remains fixed in IE7 however as shown in the image.

[image: IE7 position problem]

I have tried adding zoom:1, and applying position:relative to both select boxes and the submit button to no avail.

In Firebug if I deselect and reselect any css option, it correctly repositions. Does anyone have any ideas of a fix?

HTML -

```
<div class="filter">
            <form name="input" action="#" method="post" title="Submit">
                <span class="purple">Filter photography by:</span>


                <select id="search_type" name="brand_filter">
                    <option value="0">No filter</option>
                    <option value="1" <?= ($this->session->userdata('selected_brand_filter') == 1) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>>Brand</option>
                    <option value="2" <?= ($this->session->userdata('selected_brand_filter') == 2) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>>Hotel/Location</option>
                    <option value="3" <?= ($this->session->userdata('selected_brand_filter') == 3) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>>Region</option>
                    <option value="4" <?= ($this->session->userdata('selected_brand_filter') == 4) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>>Event</option>
                </select>
                <select id="search_category" name="category_filter">
                    <option value="0">Nothing selected</option>
                    <? if(!empty($category_filter)): ?>
                            <? foreach($category_filter as $catg): ?>
                                    <option value="<?=$catg->id?>" <?= ($this->session->userdata('selected_category_filter') == $catg->id) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>><?= $catg->name ?></option>
                            <? endforeach ?>
                    <? endif ?>
                </select>
                <input type="submit" value="" id="filter-submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>
```

CSS -

```
#filter-submit{
width:20px;
height:20px;
background: url('../images/filter_submit.jpg') no-repeat;
border:none;
cursor:pointer;
vertical-align:middle;
```

}

Comment: HTML Syntax and css code would be interesting.

Comment: You can also put your form inside a table.. that should resolv the problem, but you should give us more details about your css and html code

Comment: I've created fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jnTQC/
However, it seems to render correctly in IE7, without `submit` overlapping with `select`. Please edit it so it will correspond to your case.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, I'm not sure I'll be able to recreate it on jsfiddle however, as the second select box contents are populated dynamically with PHP depending on what is entered in the first select box - I have found a hacky js solution that seems to work for IE7 though

Answer (score 0):

You still support IE7? I feel your pain I have to as well.

I think the best thing to do would be to put it inside a table or series of div tags.

The other thing I find with IE is tweaking things in parent containers, like setting the width for your surrounding div might work. Sometimes a specified width in something like a submit button requires a specified width in all the parent object. (weird I know)

Sorry its so vague, I solve all these issues with trial and error, and just do a lot of swearing at IE for not conforming to web standards like the other browsers.

Putting your components into individual divs or table columns will definitely solve it though.

Comment: Setting float usually does it for me :)

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I still have to support IE6 on some projects - it's a sad world, I did try floating all elements left as well - same issue unfortunately

Comment: @FaddishWorm, This is answer place and this not answer, Please always use comment box for comment dont put it into answer

Comment: Pretty sure it says "Comments" ?

Answer (score 0):

OK so I've found a JS/JQuery workaround by setting a short timer, and dynamically changing a CSS property.  It isn't pretty but seems to work, unless anyone else has a better suggestion

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
    $('#search_type').change(function(){
        filtertimer = setTimeout('timeout_trigger()', 100);
    });
});

function timeout_trigger(){
    $('#filter-submit').css({'display':'block'});
    $('#filter-submit').css({'display':'inline'});
    clearTimeout(filtertimer);
}
```